# Generating JSON data with Object nested within Object

Tags: java, json, jackson

Slightly tying myself in knots here and trying to understand JSON to POJO mapping as I go but still coming across thorny issues.

I need to generate the following JSON:

```
{"primaryCustomer":
   {
       "customerClaims":[]
   }
}
```

Evidently I need a `primaryCustomer` instance who's setter takes an empty `customerClaims` array Object.  Seems simple but I can't quite get there.

Given POJOs as follows:

```
@Data
public class PrimaryCustomer {

    @JsonProperty("primaryCustomer")
    private PrimaryCustomer primaryCustomer;
    @JsonProperty("customerClaims")
    private CustomerClaims customerClaims;
}
```

And:

```
@Data
public class CustomerClaims {

    @JsonProperty("customerClaims")
    private List<Object> customerClaims = null;

}
```

And code the generate the JSON:

```
  pc = new PrimaryCustomer();
  cc = new CustomerClaims();
  
  cc.setCustomerClaims(new JSONArray());
  pc.setCustomerClaims(cc);
```

...yields:

```
{
  "primaryCustomer" : null,
  "customerClaims" : {
    "customerClaims" : []
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this resolved ?

Comment: @WilfredClement currently, no, I've not been able to generate the required JSON as declared at the top of the question

Comment: Answered, Please check and let me know

Comment: @WilfredClement thank you but I had to move on and park this. Will come back to it tomorrow ~ really appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

POJO :

```
public static @Data class Example {

        @JsonProperty("primaryCustomer")
        public PrimaryCustomer primaryCustomer;

    }

    public static @Data class PrimaryCustomer {

        @JsonProperty("customerClaims")
        public List<Object> customerClaims = null;

    }
```

Test :

```
PrimaryCustomer a = new PrimaryCustomer();
a.setCustomerClaims(new JSONArray());

Example e = new Example();
e.setPrimaryCustomer(a);

String abc = new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(e);
System.out.println(abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this POJO

````
@Data
public class PrimaryCustomer {
    @JsonProperty("customerClaims")
    private CustomerClaims customerClaims;
}```
````

Comment: thanks, that doesn't quite get me there as it misses the `primaryCustomer` single value:
`{
  "customerClaims" : 
  {
    "customerClaims" : [ ]
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Using `PrimaryCustomer` in the same class with `CustomerClaims` would not result in your desired result and may lead to `Stackoverflow` error.
You can create a `JsonEntity` class with `PrimaryCustomer` as below,

```
@Data
public class JsonEntity {

    @JsonProperty("primaryCustomer")
    private PrimaryCustomer primaryCustomer;
}

@Data
public class PrimaryCustomer {

    @JsonProperty("customerClaims")
    private CustomerClaims customerClaims;
}
```

And the code to generate the JSON:

```
json = new JsonEntity();
pc = new PrimaryCustomer();
cc = new CustomerClaims();

cc.setCustomerClaims(new JSONArray());
pc.setCustomerClaims(cc);
json.setPrimaryCustomer(pc);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: thank you.  I have separate classes for `PrimaryCustomer` and `CustomerClaims` however.  I am trying your suggestion: are you saying `JsonEntity` and `PrimaryCustomer` are in the same class file?

Comment: No.. `PrimaryCustomer` in `JsonEntity`.